# Redirect only parent page with subpages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect one of the main pages of mysite with its sub pages.
My current URL;

```
www.mysite.com/article/service-1
www.mysite.com/article/service-2
```

I want to redirect to;

```
www.mysite.com/publication/service-1
www.mysite.com/publication/service-2
```

How can I redirect so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a big vague as to what you actually try to achieve. So I will give you two answers as a starting point:

I assume you actually want an internal rewrite, *not* a rediretion. If so this will do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?article/(.*)$ /publication/$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

If you really want a redirection as you write in your question, then this variant will do, it will actually redirect the client, so change the visible URL in the browser:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?article/(.*)$ /publication/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

---

Both rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).